# Ruby on Rails Join Table with Quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I currently have two models, `List` and `Item`:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
```

Each list `has_and_belongs_to_many` items and each item `has_and_belongs_to_many` lists through the `items_lists` join table.

Currently, I can add items to the list using the following code:

```
list.items.new(id: item.id)
```

This works fine, but I would like to specify a quantity of the item when it is added to the list.

So, in the join table, I added another column called `quantity` that should store a quantity that shows however many of the item is needed. After adding the quantity column, I tried the following code to save the quantity along with a item:

```
list.items.new(id: item.id, quantity: 3)
```

However, I received an error that said `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'quantity' for Item.`

Since the way I tried appears to be incorrect, what should be done to allow for a quantity of items to be added to a list?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use a `has many through` relationship instead of the `has and belongs to many`. This will involve changing the relations on your two existing models as well as creating a third. You want to use this relationship for the many-to-many because you are storing data in addition to the two record primary keys ([has_many_through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) documentation)

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items_lists
  has_many :items, through: :items_lists
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :items_lists
end

class ItemsList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :list
end
```

additionally, your `items_lists` table should have a `list_id` and an `item_id`. so you would end up calling

```
list.items.new(item_id: item.id, quantity: 3)
```